# PayPal pro error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

[image]

1. I have created buyer and seller account from PayPal developer site.
2. Account type: **Buisness-pro**
3. And fill all right api detail's but this error is coming:-

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-12-15T12:43:12Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => a9537857c6865
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 65.1
    [BUILD] => 24616352
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration
.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 10.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
{"status":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Business-Pro can actually mean one of two things.

- Website Payments Pro 3.0 - This is what uses the DoDirectPayment API
- Payments Pro 2.0 - This uses the PayFlow API

In your case it looks like you're approved for "Pro" so you're trying to use the DoDirectPayment API, but the error you're getting means that particular API is still not enabled on your account.

This could mean that you simply cannot use DDP on your account, or it could mean PayPal simply didn't activate it for you since PayFlow would be the assumed gateway.  Technically, 2.0 should support both of those APIs.

If you call PayPal and let them know you already have DDP fully integrated and ready to go based on the fact that you had "Pro" enabled, and you would rather not re-develop everything in PayFlow due to time / cost restrictions, they will probably go ahead and enable DDP for you so that this error will go away.

Or, you could go ahead and use the PayFlow API instead.  It looks like you might possibly be using my [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/)..??  If so, you could get PayFlow setup instead of DDP within a matter of minutes.  If not, I recommend you take a look at it for future reference.  It supports pretty much every PayPal API they offer and greatly simplifies things.

If you're interested in more details on this you can check out my article on [The History of PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-payments-pro-dodirectpayment-vs-payflow/).